# cut image out of div to reveal background

Tags: css

Is it possible to cutout an image from a div revealing the background image?

I have a vertically striped background with a div that covers most of the background. The div is filled solid black. I would like an image(which is really just an outline) somewhere inside that div to "cutout" the div, revealing the background image. Is this possible?

I have thought about using the same background pattern for the image, but the vertical lines do not align correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are looking to do?  It sounds like you could make your image a png (or other type with transparencies) and just have the outline that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with CSS Masks. Here is a very detailed tutorial on a variety of masks. It covers clipping masks (coordinates on the image) and alpha masks (black and white images).

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/